# Html to pdf issue in html2pdf.it library

Tags: php, html, pdf, anchor, html2pdf

i am currently using html2pdf library in php for converting html page to pdf, it create pdf properly but google label in non clickable mode

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="https://www.google.co.in" target="_blank">Google</a>
    <a href="https://www.google.co.in">Google</a>
</body>
</html>
```